# How to build the covariance matrix with different weighted moments via GMM

Tags: covariance-matrix, method-of-moments, generalized-moments

I have two sets of moment conditions, one is IV moment with N observations but the second moment only has N_1 observations, N_1<N.
How to build the covariance matrix? Appreciate for any replies!